# How to resolve - method using in object WebSocket is deprecated: Use accept with an Akka streams flow instead

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-stream, playframework-2.5

I am trying to migrate my application from play 2.4 to 2.5 While migrating I am trying to remove the deprecated functions. One such warning that I am receiving is **"method using in object WebSocket is deprecated: Use accept with an Akka streams flow instead"**

Below is the function that I need to change, How do I refactor this code to use Akka Stream Flows.

```
def test =  WebSocket.using[String] { request =>
   val in = Iteratee.ignore[String]
   val out = Enumerator("<response>Test</response>").andThen(Enumerator.eof)
   Logger.warn("Some warning")
   (in, out)
}
```

I tried going through [How to refactor this code by using akka streams.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994575/how-to-refactor-this-code-by-using-akka-streams) but could not get much. I am new to scala and play :(

Any pointers or examples would be of great help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWebSockets#handling-websockets-with-akka-streams-and-actors) to implement Akka Streams flow. That's quite straightforward.